# Oracle and React: How to keep order for next time page loads

Tags: javascript, reactjs, oracle

I'm really new to all of this, but the jist is that I have a drag and drop table that I created with react.

The values are pulled from a table I created in oracle (200 rows about 23  columns).

currently I have an id I added when I did my ETL to keep things in proper order. My goal is to update the oracle table when I drag an item so it can keep order.

I dont really see a way of doing this without updating every row. I am keeping history, so I am not updating rows, I am inserting new rows.

Basically I would like something I can sort on when I pull the table in so I can keep the exact order of the last drag and drop.

Any suggestions would be helpful, the only thing I can think of is to map a new index to each and to then grab the key with the new index and update each row with the new index.

Is there a different approach that is more efficient that I can look into. Keep in mind that I am new so I would have to research most of all you say more than likely, so if there is a baby step it would be best to let me know I probably have to look into that.

Edit: I should mention that I am using Node.js and oracledb to pull the info from our oracle tables version 12.

I receive the data as a json, but the table itself does not save json, which isn't out of the picture, I just have standard rows and columns. Truth be told, I tried to save as json through this setup and just gave up and moved on to standard data types.

Comment: Is the question here targeting an entire result set, or just the data of one (or a few) pages in your UI?  If the latter, just cache the data in React and do the sorting on the JavaScript side.

Comment: Is caching in react similar to saving a cookie on the clients side, or does it just get cached on my server. Do I literally just search for caching in react? 

The app itself is for our sales directors to get ready to create an org chart. So basically, it is a project setup for when we start planning for the next year.

Overall this is just one step in the process, but the table itself will be used throughout the project, but to be honest this is the first thing I started with. I haven't built anything else out yet.

Comment: I don't know anything about React, so I may be way off base with what you are trying to do, but when you talk about 'order' in connection with tables, you need to keep in mind that as far as the table is concerned there is no 'order' of rows.  The tables are a 'heap' (un-ordered) structure.  If you want "ordering" from the database, you _have_ to use the ORDER BY clause in your SELECT statement.

Comment: @EdStevens I think there is some confusion, the HTML TABLE has order, and this table is pulled from an oracle table. So I have the ability to manipulate order somewhat. When I first created the oracle table, I added an id which is sorted by when I create the HTML. In the HTML I am able to drag the HTML table rows around.. When I do  this, I want to save back to the table but have the ability to create order. 

Maybe I can create a second table that is just takes the keys of the main table and updates the index, then do a join on this table to pull in my info.

Biggest concern is efficiency

Comment: Seems like the complexity is based on the need to keep the history, no? How do you intend on using the history?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding "keeping history", have a look at this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EtgYbX0Roxg Maybe Flashback Data Archive would be a better option. Or maybe Temporal Validity can help simplify your queries with the current model.

As for "updating every row", I think you mean just the rows that have a "display sequence" higher than the one that was just reordered, right?

One design pattern you could consider is switching to a single update, say upon clicking a save button, rather than using the drop event for each change. That may still require updating many rows, but at least you'd do it less frequently.

If you want to continue to save on drop and you want to minimize the work in the database, you could consider using a "display_previous_id" column instead of a "display_sequence" column. The idea is that each row would point to the row before it. You can use Oracle's CONNECT BY operator to get the data back out in the correct order.

With this change, updating the column of a given row would always require three updates. First, the row being moved must point to its new parent. Second, the row previously pointing to the parent must point to the new row. Finally, the row that's pointing to the row being moved must point to the previous parent of the row being moved. While more efficient, the tradeoff is that you need to be very careful when it comes to data integrity.

Here's an example:

```
create table colors (
    id          number  
                constraint colors_id_pk primary key,
    name        varchar2(255) not null,
    previous_id number
                constraint colors_previous_id_fk
                references colors (id)
);

insert into colors (id, name, previous_id) values (1, 'Red', null);
insert into colors (id, name, previous_id) values (2, 'Orange', 1);
insert into colors (id, name, previous_id) values (3, 'Yellow', 2);
insert into colors (id, name, previous_id) values (4, 'Green', 3);
insert into colors (id, name, previous_id) values (5, 'Blue', 4);
insert into colors (id, name, previous_id) values (6, 'Indigo', 5);
insert into colors (id, name, previous_id) values (7, 'Violet', 6);
```

Here's how you would get the values out in the correct order:

```
select level, name
from colors
connect by prior id = previous_id
start with previous_id is null
order by level;
```

Which returns:

```
1 Red
2 Orange
3 Yellow
4 Green
5 Blue
6 Indigo
7 Violet
```

Imagine someone drags Indigo (6) between Orange (2) and Yellow (3). Indigo would need to point its previous_id to Orange, as that's the parent. Yellow, which was previously pointing at Orange, would need to point to Indigo. Finally, Violet, which was previously pointing to Indigo, would need to point to Blue.

You would want to do this as a single unit of work, and you'd want to serialize such updates. To do that, you'd use a PL/SQL stored procedure like the following:

```
create or replace procedure move_color(
  p_color_id        in colors.id%type,
  p_new_previous_id in colors.id%type
)

is

  -- There is only one record without a parent (the first color
  -- to display). This cursor will lock that row to serialize
  -- update operations on the table through this procedure.
  cursor lock_cur
  is
    select 1
    from colors
    where previous_id is null
    for update;

  cursor color_cur
  is
    select *
    from colors
    where id = move_color.p_color_id
    for update;

  l_color_rec color_cur%rowtype;

begin

  open lock_cur;

  open color_cur;
  fetch color_cur into l_color_rec;

  update colors
  set previous_id = l_color_rec.previous_id
  where previous_id = l_color_rec.id;

  if move_color.p_new_previous_id is null
  then
    update colors
    set previous_id = l_color_rec.id
    where previous_id is null;
  else
    update colors
    set previous_id = l_color_rec.id
    where previous_id = move_color.p_new_previous_id;
  end if;

  update colors
  set previous_id = move_color.p_new_previous_id
  where current of color_cur;

  close color_cur;

  close lock_cur;

end;
```

You would run this to do the change:

```
begin

  move_color(6, 2);

end;
```

And if you rerun the query you'd see this:

```
1 Red
2 Orange
3 Indigo
4 Yellow
5 Green
6 Blue
7 Violet
```

Now, no matter how many rows you have, only three need to be updated. As you can see, the data model is a little more complex, so you'll have to determine if the ends justify the means for your app.

Comment: Thanks Dan, so working through it would the new data look as follows?

    1 RED null, 2 orange 1, 3 yellow 6, 4 green 3, 5 blue 4, 6 indigo 2, 7 violet 5?

Thanks for showing me hierarchy. I was able to create my sale hierarchy a lot faster.

Comment: Yes, that's what the data would look like after the move. I'm happy it helped!

Comment: Hey, I wanted to add a few more parameters on the move_color procedure. quick question, are the  p_color_id        in colors.id%type, the "colors.id" is that a field or are you just declaring an id? I wanted to add a text field for channel and a timestamp field. my id field is called oid and my previous_id is called pid.

Comment: Nevermind, I got it. I was having issues with a join on a timestamp. disregard. Thanks again so much!

Comment: Hey Dan, I saw you active on oracledb for node. I cant figure out how to call this procedure from my node server. I have oracledb setup already (thats what I am using to get my data for the app), Everytime I try it just hangs. I have tried most of the examples, but they are all making the procedure in the file, should I just do the same thing? This procedure is already created in oracle.

Comment: One of the most flexible ways to invoke stored procedures is via an anonymous block. There's an example in the doc here: https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/doc/api.html#plsqlproc You would just swap out the name of the procedure as well as the bind variable names and values.

Comment: Thanks Dan, I've tried all of those already. I'm onto some of the pool examples. with the above I would not have an out right? Every example seems to have an out, and for whatever reason is seems like this should be simple enough. The above I am getting undefined. To be fair I did have blocking session going on, so nothing was happening because of that, so I need to revisit. I will start saving off what I have tried and if I can't get it will post over on the github. Thanks again!

Comment: dang. it just hung gotta contact dba to terminate blocking session even with oracledb.getPool().close(10); just saw note on DISABLE_OOB=ON;  

just for context, I mixed https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/blob/master/examples/connectionpool.js with what you linked. put what you linked in the dostuff function.